# Slide transition from one group of images to another

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is what I have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/8r302nqk/

```js
jQuery('.button1').click(function() {
  jQuery('.group1').css('transform', 'translateX(-200%)');
});

jQuery('.button2').click(function() {
  jQuery('.group1').css('transform', 'translateX(0%)');
});
```

```css
.pagewrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.pagewrap img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.hero-bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.hero-bg img {
  width: 100%;
}

.btnwrap {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0 1%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  color: hotpink;
}

.group1,
.group2 {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.one6 {
  width: 16.6667%;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagewrap">
  <div class="hero-bg">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/1500/830">
  </div>
  <div class="btnwrap">
    <div class="button button1">GROUP 1
    </div>
    <div class="button button2">GROUP 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="groupwrap">
    <div class="group1">
      <div class="one6">
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200?random=1">
      </div>
      <div class="one6">
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200?random=2">
      </div>
      <div class="one6">
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200?random=3">
      </div>
      <div class="one6">
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200?random=4">
      </div>
      <div class="one6">
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200?random=5">
      </div>
      <div class="one6">
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200?random=6">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group2">
      <div class="one6">
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200?random=7">
      </div>
      <div class="one6">
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200?random=8">
      </div>
      <div class="one6">
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200?random=9">
      </div>
      <div class="one6">
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200?random=10">
      </div>
      <div class="one6">
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200?random=11">
      </div>
      <div class="one6">
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200?random=12">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What i'm trying to accomplish is when the page loads the user can only see the first group of images. The second group of images should be off the right side of the page inline with the first group and not visible. When you click the group 2 button, the images in `.group1` should slide off to the left while the `.group2` images slide in from the right taking the place of group1. Then if you click the group 1 button the opposite should happen showing group1 again. I'm having difficulties getting the second group inline with the first group while keeping the groups centered as they appear now.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need an opposing style for `.group2` so that `.group1` starts with being shown and `.group2` is out of view

css

```
.group2 {
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}
```

js / button events

```
jQuery('.button1').click(function() {
  jQuery('.group1').css('transform', 'translateX(0)');
  jQuery('.group2').css('transform', 'translateX(-200%)');
});

jQuery('.button2').click(function() {
  jQuery('.group1').css('transform', 'translateX(-200%)');
  jQuery('.group2').css('transform', 'translateX(0)');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8r302nqk/2/

you may also need to `translateY` for `group2` to compensate for `group1` height

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. What I did to get `.group1` and `.group2` on the same line is to position them absolute instead of relative, and I started with `.group2` off the side with `transform: translateX(200%);` as in MikeM's post.  Then I changed the `transfrom: translateX` values with the jQuery click events to slide them side to side. The changes I made from the original post are here:

```
.group1,
.group2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 2s;
}
.group2 {
  transform: translateX(200%);
}

jQuery('.button1').click(function() {
  jQuery('.group1').css('transform', 'translateX(0)');
  jQuery('.group2').css('transform', 'translateX(200%)');
});

jQuery('.button2').click(function() {
  jQuery('.group1').css('transform', 'translateX(-200%)');
  jQuery('.group2').css('transform', 'translateX(0)');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/at74ert7/6/